# Fixing bad fonts in web pages in Firefox on Windows 7

Tags: firefox, fonts, windows-7

See the image below which is a doctored screenshot of the view of https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive and is not concerning the fonts when editing a Google Docs.

[image]

The font rendering is bad, relative to what you see in other web pages.

What is the proper way to fix this?

I'm using latest Firefox on Windows 7 Enterprise. This is a fresh installation of Windows 7.  I've noticed this problem before so it is not unique to this installation.

Originally I thought this was unique to Google Drive, but I see this also on http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17877/how-to-manage-autoarchive-in-outlook-2010/ shown below:

[image]

Compare that with the same rendered on a Linux machine using recent Firefox 32-bit:

[image]

Turning off [hardware acceleration](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/952985#answer-415717) has no effect:

[image]

In response to the comment "", here are my unmodified "cleartype" items in my about:config:

[image]

After turning on ClearType in the Control Panel, http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17877/how-to-manage-autoarchive-in-outlook-2010/ shows as:

[image]

As to the about:config comment, the only setting I found that was changed was **font.internaluseonly.changed**. Turning it on and off had no effect on the fonts that I could tell (and this was with cleartype enabled):

[image]

Comment: Do you have cleartype enabled and tuned? [Make text easier to read using ClearType](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-text-easier-read-cleartype#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: Have you changed any of the firefox default font settings?

Comment: enable ClearType and also go into about:config and scan for anything related to "font" and "cleartype", I'ld say.

Comment: @larkey: I have not modified the "cleartype" items in about:config. I'll inspect the "font" items in a bit and update back here.

Comment: @DavidPostill: I've enabled cleartype and it seems to have improved things. What's odd is when I then turn it off, the fonts look "dimmer" than they were before I enabled it.

Comment: @larkey: I've posted the results of looking for "font" items in about:config and only found **font.internaluseonly.changed**. Changing that had no effect.

Comment: @DavidPostill: If you post your "use cleartype" as an answer, I'll mark it as "the" answer.  Thanks also for the tips from larkey.

Comment: @bgoodr Done, answer posted.

Answer (score 1):

#### The font rendering is bad, relative to what you see in other web pages.

> What is the proper way to fix this?

In your case it looks like ClearType is either turned off or needs to be "retuned".

Note:

- Check your font configuration in Firefox to ensure that the fonts you're using support ClearType
- Web download fonts may not support ClearType.
- Microsoft fonts supplied with Windows support ClearType.

---

#### Make text easier to read using ClearType

> **To turn on ClearType**
>
> 1. Open the ClearType Text Tuner by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the
>      search box, type cleartype, and then click Adjust ClearType text.
> 2. On the first page of the tuner, select the Turn on ClearType check box, click Next, and then continue clicking Next until you reach
>      the last page.
> 3. On the last page of the tuner, click Finish to turn on ClearType. Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an
>      administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide
>      confirmation.
>
> Note
>
> - For ClearType to be effective, you should have a video card and monitor that support a color setting of at least 256 colors. You'll
>     get the best results with High color (24-bit) or Highest color
>     (32-bit) support.
>
> **To tune ClearType**
>
> You can use the ClearType Text Tuner to adjust the legibility of the
>   text on your screen to your visual preference.
>
> 1. Open the ClearType Text Tuner by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the
>      search box, type cleartype, and then click Adjust ClearType text.
> 2. Make sure the Turn on ClearType check box is selected, and then click Next. On each page, click the text sample that looks best to
>      you.
> 3. On the last page of the tuner, click Finish to save your settings. Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an
>      administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide
>      confirmation.
>
> Note
>
> - If you upgraded to Windows 7 from Windows XP or Windows Vista and the ClearType Tuner PowerToy for Windows XP is still installed on your
>     PC, you might want to uninstall it. The ClearType Text Tuner is
>     included with Windows 7 and can replace the ClearType Tuner PowerToy.
>     For more information about uninstalling programs, see Uninstall or
>     change a program.

Source [Make text easier to read using ClearType](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-text-easier-read-cleartype#1TC=windows-7)